# AST Parser get the name of Java class

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree

I am using Eclipse's AST Parser to parse a standalone Java files. This is my below overridden code to get the CompilationUnit (ie Java file) details:

```
@Override
public boolean visit(CompilationUnit node) {
    System.out.println("Compilation unit: " + node.getPackage().getName());
    System.out.println("Imports: " + node.imports());
    System.out.println("Class Name: " + ??); //How to get this?
    return super.visit(node);
}
```

As you can see from above code, I am able to get package name, imports etc from `CompilationUnit`. But the main problem I am facing is, I am not able to get name of the class. I tried printing `node.toString()` it prints entire source code, I tried with `node.getClass();` but it returns me name as `CompilationUnit`. What I want is name of the class of the file which I am parsing. Is there any in-build methods using I can get this info?

Comment: Hi Pradeep, Did you got it. Can you please tell me how you got class name.  Thanks! Sangeeta

Comment: @Sangeeta Yes I got, I asked this bit long time, I need to checkback my old code. Will let you know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In Java, a compilation unit is not equal to a single class.**

You can define multiple classes (with package-private access) for example. On the other hand you do not always have a public class within a compilation unit (the restriction is that you may have only one public class, and if you have, its name must be identical to the name of the compilation unit).

I believe you should process with the accept process on your `CompilationUnit` and write the `visit()` methods for classes too.